# Stateful button script blocks form submit?

Tags: button, wicket, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a [Twitter Bootstrap Button JS](https://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons), Stateful button part.

Everything works as expected, but sometimes when button is clicked - it "blocks" form submit event. Then form is not submitted and button is not changed back to enabled.

Basically at the end I get not submitted form and disabled button.

What is wrong?

Markup - nothing special here, just some wicket markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" wicket:id="submit" type="submit">
    <i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>&nbsp;<wicket:message key="label"/>
</button>
```

And button class. Just appending attributes required for JS to work and executing script when page is loaded:

```
public class StatefullButton extends Button {

    public StatefullButton(String id, IModel<String> loadingText) {
        super(id);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(AttributeModifier.append("data-loading-text", loadingText));
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(BootstrapButtonPluginResourceReference.get());
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript("$('#" + this.getMarkupId() + "').button();");
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript("$('#" + this.getMarkupId() + "').click(" +
            "function(){" +
                "var btn = $(this) \n" +
                "btn.button('loading')" +
            "})");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Added html markup and java code for button. All JS is original from Twitter Bottstrap#Buttons

Comment: Noticed, that I can reproduce problem when moving mouse pointer away from the button, VERY fast after clicking it. Not 100%.

Comment: I'm not sure about the cause. At first sight it might be a javascript problem. But I have to go deeper in it (would build my own test case,...). Think this will need some time :( I Hope that in the meantime someone else has a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem using button, but found workaround using SubmitLink and overriding `getTriggerJavaScript` like this.

```
@Override
protected String getTriggerJavaScript(){
    String script = super.getTriggerJavaScript();
    String loadingScript = "$(this).button('loading');";
    return loadingScript + script;
}
```